# Finding Parabola equations with 2 points.

Tags: calculus

problem give 2 points and we know that none of them are vertex,
how to find the equation[image]

Comment: You can't.  The set of all parabolas (*or lines*) is a three-dimensional subspace of the vector space of all polynomials.  Knowing only two pieces of information about the parabola will not uniquely determine which parabola it is.  The solution set will be one dimensional.  Take for example "Find the parabola passing through $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  It could have been $f(x)=x(x-1)$, it could have been $f(x)=2x(x-1)$, or in general it could have been $f(x)=\alpha x(x-1)$ for any $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: thanks dude,so I can't find the equation, can we speak about the a,b,c (the Parabola coefficients) 's range?

Comment: Given points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, you know that $ax_1^2+bx_1+c=y_1$ and $ax_2^2+bx_2+c=y_2$. This is a system of two linear equations in three variables. In almost all cases, there will be no restriction on the range of $a$, $b$, or $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two points on a parabola, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ (*where $x_1\neq x_2$*), we try to find as much information as we can about the set of parabolas which pass through these points: $y=ax^2+bx+c$

Using the information given by those two points, this tells us the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} ax_1^2+bx_1+c=y_1\\ ax_2^2+bx_2+c=y_2\end{cases}$$

Rewriting this in terms of a matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2&x_1&1\\x_2^2&x_2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Solve the system using familiar methods (*such as via row reduction*)

---

For example, finding the set of parabolas which pass through the points $(0,1)$ and $(3,0)$ will produce the matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\9&3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Row reducing the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}0&0&1&1\\9&3&1&0\end{array}\right]$ yields $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&\frac{1}{3}&0&-\frac{1}{9}\\0&0&1&1\end{array}\right]$ implying that $c=1$ and $a=-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{3}b$

Thus, all polynomials passing through those two points can be written as:

$$f(x)=(-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{3}t)x^2+tx+1$$

for some $t\in\Bbb R$

Comment: @marshalcraft The solution set isn't even a monoid.  It isn't even closed under addition.  It can act as a basis vector for a one dimensional subspace of $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ (*the space of continuous functions over $\Bbb R$*) however, but I don't see how that is relevant to the current question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only required to find **ONE possible** parabola that suits the graph given, here is an approach.

Note that $x=4$ and for some $\alpha>-2$ are the roots of the parabola. Since the parabola opens downwards, we write 
$$y=-(x-4)(x-\alpha)$$

From the point $(-2,-2)$, 
$$-2=-(-6)(-2-\alpha)\implies\alpha=-\frac53$$

So the parabola can be

$$y=-(x-4)(x+\frac53)$$

To further verify the equation, we have $y=\frac{20}3>0$ when $x=0$, which is indeed true.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parabola then it's a quadratic equation. You have a system of equations. Using f'' 's notation, $$ax_1^2+bx_1+c=y_1 \, \land \, ax_2^2+bx_2+c=y_2$$  2 equations and 3 unknowns $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

If the axis is vertical, we have *three* constants so we need to determine *three* constants in:

$$ y= a x^2 + b x + c $$

We require *three* points. Two points would not suffice.

For completeness..

If the axis is horizontal, we also find three constants in $x= a y^2 + b y + c. $

If the parabola axis is inclined to x-, y-, axes, then we need  to find four constants in $y = a x +b + \sqrt{ c x +d }. $